# Number and occurrence in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

My homework is bag implementation using arrays where you can add and remove numbers as you please. So far I've managed to do everything except the list of numbers and occurs, which is supposed to look like this:

[image: img]

I have no idea where to begin, so some pointers would be nice, please and thank you. (note: I'm not allowed to use anything but arrays, so arraylist, collection etc can't help me.)

EDIT: I created another array for counts and the code seems to be working fine in some cases. However, sometimes when I run it, it gives me a completely wrong output and I don't know how to fix it? For example, if I put in the numbers (in this order) 11, 22, 11, 33, 11, 22 I get this back:

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bag {

int index = 0;
int[] array = new int[50];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    Bag bag = new Bag();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (x == 0) {
        System.out.print("Add(A), Delete(D), Find(F), Size(S), Min(m), Max(M), List(L), Quit(Q) >> ");
        char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
        switch (c) {
            case 'A':
                int y = scan.nextInt();
                bag.Add(y);
                break;
            case 'D':
                int d = scan.nextInt();
                bag.Delete(d);
                break;
            case 'F':
                int z = scan.nextInt();
                bag.Find(z);
                break;
            case 'S':
                bag.Size();
                break;
            case 'm':
                bag.Min();
                break;
            case 'M':
                bag.Max();
                break;
           case 'L': bag.List();
                break;
            case 'Q': bag.Quit();
            }
        }

}

public void Add(int y) {
    array[index] = y;
    index++;
    System.out.println("   " + y + " is added to the Bag. ");
}

    public void Delete(int d) {
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    if (d == array[i]) {
        while (i < index) {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("   " + d + " is deleted from the Bag.");
        index--;
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("   Cannot delete " + d
        + ". It does not exist in the Bag.");

    }   

public void Find(int z)
   {
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] == z) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("   There is (" + count + ") " + z
                + " in the Bag.");

          }
public void Size() {
    System.out.println("  There are " + index + " numbers in the Bag.");
}

public void Min() {
    int min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        if(min > array[i]) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   The minimum number in the Bag is " + min + ".");
}
public void Max() {
    int max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        if(max < array[i]) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   The maximum number in the Bag is " + max + ".");
}
public void Quit() {
    System.out.println("Bye…");
}

public int Count(int c) {
    int elements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == c) {
            elements++;
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
public void delete(int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (c == array[i]) {
            while (i < index) {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                i++;
            }
            index--;
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void List() {
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
    System.out.println("| Number | Occurs |");
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");

    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        if(Count(array[i]) == 1){

      System.out.printf("|%8d|%8d|\n", array[i], Count(array[i]));
      System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("|%8d|%8d|\n", array[i], Count(array[i]));
            System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
            for(int j = 0; j <= Count(array[i]); j++){
                delete(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You just need to loop through all the indexes in the array, and for each one, if there are any occurrences, print a line with that information.

Comment: It might be easier if you use one array for the numbers and another one for the counts.

Comment: Are you permitted to use a custom Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have problem with the List() method. Change it to:

```
public void List() {
System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
System.out.println("| Number | Occurs |");
System.out.println("+--------+--------+");

while(index > 0){
    int del = array[0];
    int count = Count(del);
    System.out.printf("|%8d|%8d|\n", del, count);
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
    for(int j = 0; j < count; j++){
        delete(del);
    }
}
```

}

```
+--------+--------+
| Number | Occurs |
+--------+--------+
|      11|       3|
+--------+--------+
|      22|       2|
+--------+--------+
|      33|       1|
+--------+--------+
```

Also change array.length to index will allow for 0 to be added.

```
public int Count(int c) {
    int elements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (array[i] == c) {
            elements++;
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
public int count(int c) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        count += (c == array[i]) ? 1 : 0; 
    return count;
}

public void list() {
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
    System.out.println("| Number | Occurs |");
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
    printRec(array);
}

private void printRec(int...ints) {
    int constant = ints[0];
    if (constant == 0) return;
    int count = count(constant);
    System.out.printf("|%8d|%8d|\n", constant, count);
    System.out.println("+--------+--------+");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        delete(constant);
    printRec(array);
}
```

To get result call void `bag.list()`. The problem was in getting array data while it's changing. Recursive mehod will get data, then change `array` data, then run itself with new data.

> Also remember, that methods always must start from `lowercase`.
>   It's not a functional mistake, but a [rule](https://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html).